# How do I get a long embedded text block to wrap instead of scrolling?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to embed a text block and have the contents wrap instead of having to scroll all of the way to the right to see all of the text. For example, I'm trying to embed the text found at this url: http://web.content.cddbp.net/cds/2.0?id=50327B23DC0DA5CA&client=10395648&class=biography&type=text/plain&tag=027cnucLRazjMWFwDL1us0JeVsBV16hiFCvn0Zjk.QnTbK.sO3pP2yAA in a page using this code:

```
<object type="text/html" data="http://web.content.cddbp.net/cds/2.0?id=50327B23DC0DA5CA&client=10395648&class=biography&type=text/plain&tag=027cnucLRazjMWFwDL1us0JeVsBV16hiFCvn0Zjk.QnTbK.sO3pP2yAA"></object>
```

and all of my embedded text just shows up as a long single line that scrolls far to the right. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't see the problem you're referring to. Seems to wrap just fine: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7EccY/)

Comment: Although the jsfiddle posted by Mark M looks fine for me, try adding a meta tag:

    `<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=yes, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, target-densitydpi=1">`

or add a `overflow: scroll` to the object.

More information such as the browser or device you're using would help.

Comment: Where on the page do I put the meta tag? I tried just adding it to the top of the page and I don't see any difference. The device/browser doesn't matter - I'm using firefox, but this is just for a test project I'm working on so it doesn't need to be cross-browser

Comment: I take it back - the browser does seem to matter. The jsfiddle page works fine in Chrome, but not firefox